# Jquery apply function to single div not to all at once

Tags: jquery

I'm not very able with jquery and I want my function work just on the hovered div.
I got several divs (n from 1 to 250) with images and text and I would like on mouseover something css changes.
HTML is: `

```
<div id="serie" class="nspArtPage active nspCol1">
  <div id="archivio" class="nspArt nspCol4" style="padding:0 20px 20px 0;clear:both;">
     its divs with text and image
  <div id="archivio" class="nspArt nspCol4" style="padding:0 20px 20px 0;">
     its divs with text and image
  <div .... and so on </div>
</div>
```

`but I can change it, adding code to have different ids (I've already tried.)
In my "jQuery(document).ready(function()" I call that function`

```
jQuery('#serie').on('mouseenter', '#archivio', function( event ) {
    jQuery("#archivio #arphoto p.nspText").css("display","block");
    jQuery("#archivio #bkgpanel").css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");
}).on('mouseleave', '#archivio', function( event ) {
    jQuery("#archivio #arphoto p.nspText").css("display","none");
    jQuery("#archivio #bkgpanel").css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
});
```

`At this moment every time I go on a div, all divs have same behavior.
I would like to have single behavior.
I tried with each function, with delegate function but I suppose that is not the correct approach.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id="archivio"` multiple time.

**IDs must be unique**, use a comman class instead

```
jQuery('#serie').on('mouseenter', '.archivio', function( event ) {
    //do something        
}).on('mouseleave', '.archivio', function( event ) {
    //do something      
});
```

And modify your HTML as

```
<div  class="archivio nspArt nspCol4"
```

Comment: While correct, it's really the "do something" part that they were asking about in their question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, OP has to post more code as its difficult to save what `#archivio #arphoto p.nspText` will refer to. There is a high possiblity `id="arphoto"` must be dyplicate

Comment: I think it's obvious the intention is to only modify the elements inside the specific div the event was triggered for, not all elements that would match that selector. You don't need any extra code for that.

Comment: @AdrianoD'Abrusco, I am suggesting you to use class name. like `<div  class="archivio nspArt nspCol4"` and in event handler use `jQuery(this).find("#arphoto p.nspText")`

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs need to be unique, you won't get reliable results if you have multiple elements with `id="archivio"`. Use a class instead. So:

```
<div id="archivio" class="nspArt nspCol4" style="padding:0 20px 20px 0;clear:both;">
```

becomes:

```
<div class="archivio nspArt nspCol4" style="padding:0 20px 20px 0;clear:both;">
```

You'll also want to use `this` inside the event handler to refer to the specific element that triggered the event, then use `.find()` to find the elements inside them you want. Something like this:

```
jQuery('#serie').on('mouseenter', '.archivio', function( event ) {
    jQuery(this).find("#arphoto p.nspText").css("display","block");
    jQuery(this).find("#bkgpanel").css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)");
}).on('mouseleave', '.archivio', function( event ) {
    jQuery(this).find("#arphoto p.nspText").css("display","none");
    jQuery(this).find("#bkgpanel").css("background-color","rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
});
```